# Psi ability ceiling?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

If my x-com soldier has already unlocked all 3 tiers of psi abilities is there any additional accrued benefit to their using psi abilities in battle, or should I be giving other "gifted children" opportunities to level?

Comment: Note there will be a 4th psi ability unlocked in the volunteer when you attack the temple ship. But this is unrelated to experience.

Answer (score 3):

No, you should give the opportunity to other gifted if possible. That said, they can be excellent for setup so that other gifted can get more chances at using their psy abilities.

Psy inspiration can boost other gifted's attack chance (successful psy attack gives 3 xp while failed ones give only 1), mind fray can be a way to set up for another mind fray kill on mid-high HP targets like mutons (making it viable to not use weapon fire to kill it), and mind control can be used to incapacitate aliens so that you can kill all of them w/ psy attacks rather than weapon fire.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Definitely! As there are no more psi abilities to unlock, you might even risk your Soldier getting injured critically and thus lowering his/her Will permanently. This will overall affect the effectiveness of your psi abilities against the X-Rays.